# babel target to old version browser, it raise export 'jsx' (imported as '_jsx') was not found in 'react/jsx-runtime' (possible exports: __esModule)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

following is my babel.config.js, it raise err `export 'jsx' (imported as '_jsx') was not found in 'react/jsx-runtime' (possible exports: __esModule)`

but when change chrome:54 to chrome: 74, no err is raised

I expect my app is support chrome:54(chrome min version to support es6), **how should i do?**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": 3, // or 2,
            "targets": {
                "chrome": "54"
            },
            "exclude": ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"]
        }],
        ["@babel/preset-react", {
            "runtime": "automatic"
        }]
    ]
}
```

my babel deps:

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, babel ignore some deps will fix this err

see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717337/6011193