# babel + core-js + webpack make code support old chrome, many node_modules file raise "export ... was not found" error

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, core-js

I reproduce err in [this project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1dV2bR3-0bIhb0MPdMzsFA7mAik0alO/view?usp=sharing)

following is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": 3, // or 2,
            "targets": {
                "chrome": "54" // babel is for debug, it make code compatible android webview, so compatible my genymotion android webview is enough
            },
            "exclude": ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"]
        }],
    ]
}
```

when `npx webpack serve`, it raise many similar errs like `export 'default' (imported as 'stripAnsi') was not found in './modules/strip-ansi/index.js' (module has no exports)`

when babel.config.js set chrome:54, it raise err; when set chrome:74, not err, but I expect all code support chrome 54 **and I must use core-js to apply polyfill**, so how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Some deps use module.exports will conflict with babel + corejs, so make babel ignore these deps, and even no babel, most popular deps native support old browser(like react, react-dom use module.exports, they natively support very old browser)

in my case, only little deps cause this err, so i use babel.config.js "exclude" like following:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": "3.19.0", // or 2,
            "targets": {
                "android": "54" // babel is for debug, it make code compatible android webview, so compatible my genymotion android webview is enough
            },
            "exclude": ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"]
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
    ],
    exclude: [/node_modules\/react/, /node_modules\/urijs/, /node_modules\/axios/]
}
```

**also**, if maybe deps cause this err, use babel.config.js "include" fix it